# Python Simple program iteration through list

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I'm making a simple program to test.
Here is the code:

```
list1 = [1,2,d,,t,h,7,8]

for x in list1:
    if x ==
```

I'm trying to iterate in my list and check to see which item is a string and which is 
a number(I know its basic, but im new). So what would be a correct way to write this line
of code. All suggestions would help

Answer (score 2):

In Python, use the builtin `isinstance(variable, type)` to test whether a variable is of a given type.

The `type` variable can also be a tuple of several types to test against.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my program's problem

Answer (score 1):

Your list is a little messed up. If those letters are supposed to be strings, it should look like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,'d','t','h',7,8]
```

Otherwise they are referring to variables.

**To check if number**

```
for x in list1:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        ...
```

**To check if string**

```
for x in list1:
    if isinstance(x, str):
       ...
```

**Combination**

```
for x in list1:
    if x.isinstance(x, int):
        ....
    elif isinstance(x, str)L
       ....
```

Comment: `isdigit` is a string function to detect if all characters in the string are numeric. In the OP's sample, the integer values are not strings, but actual integers.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire fixed that. he didn't have quotations around the letters either so I didn't know if maybe some would have quotes around them.

Answer (score 1):

This should print the type of each element in your list

```
for item in list1:
    print type(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list contains purely numbers and strings:

```
for x in list1:
    if type(x) == str:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something for numbers
```

Comment: `isinstance` is generally preferred practice over `type(x)=='. Given an object that is an instance of class B which is a subclass of A, `type(obj)==A` will evaluate as False, but `isinstance(obj,A)` will return True.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone is giving answers similar to my old one (see below), I'll try something else.You can easily make 2 lists that separate ints and strings with Python's list comprehensions:

```
strings = [x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, str)]
intlist = [x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Using list comprehensions made the code more compact and easier to understand.

Old response:

```
list1 = [1, 4, 5, '5', '3', 3, 'a']
for x in list1:
    if(isinstance(x, str)):
        print(str(x) + ' is a string.')
    else:
        print(str(x) + ' is not a string.')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this one,

```
list1=[1,2,'d','t','h',7,8]

for data in list1:
    if type(data) is str:
        #do something with it
    elif type(data) is int:
        #do something with it
```

you can try something like this or any of those methods mentioned from other answers in the python interpreter to see it works -

```
>> type(1) is str
```

and you would get

```
>> False
```